# store values from database into combobox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, oledb

I'm trying to write a program using SQL and OleDB and I get an error while the Program is running.
the program first counts the number of rows in the table(access table which called 'tblCodons')
and storage the number as integer in j.

then the program stores all the rows (from a specific column which called 'codonsFullName') in comboBox1.
the code is below
I get this ERROR:**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Invalid SQL statement;Required values​​' DELETE ',' INSERT ',' PROCEDURE ',' SELECT 'or' UPDATE**

the code:

```
int j=0;
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn1.Open();
string sqlCount= "SET @j= SELECT COUNT(tblCodons.codonsFullName) FROM tblCodons";
OleDbCommand counter = new OleDbCommand(sqlCount, conn1);
counter.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn1.Close();

OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn2.Open();
string sqlFill = "SELECT tblCodons.codonsFullName FROM tblCodons";
OleDbCommand fill = new OleDbCommand(sqlFill, conn2);
fill.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader dataReader = fill.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetString(i));
}
```

Comment: Did you try in second query do not use tblCodons.codonsFullName, but just codonsFullName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this answer here as an explanation for fixing your code as it currently exists, but also want to point out that I recommend going with Kamal's solution; it only queries the database once.

This line is probably your error:

```
string sqlCount= "SET @j= SELECT COUNT(tblCodons.codonsFullName) FROM tblCodons";
```

change to

```
string sqlCount= "SELECT COUNT(tblCodons.codonsFullName) FROM tblCodons";
```

You'll want to change your code to obtain the result of that first query like this:

```
j = counter.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: but how can i save it to an integer variable?

Comment: @user1017315 See above. I agree with Kamal though, executing two queries against the database is overkill.

Comment: when i try your solution i steel get the error :System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: @user1017315 Sure, that's the error pointed out in the comments for the other answer, re: GetString(int).

Comment: its giving me just the first row multipule the number of rows. how can i fix it?

Comment: You need to add another call to Read() inside your loop.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to need the count only for the loop. Also I do not understand why you are executing fill.ExecuteNonQuery() before executing is as a reader.

Also setting @j (if it did work) in a sql query has no scope to a local variable j in the code you are trying to set.

You should only need the following code (apologies for any syntax errors)

```
OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn2.Open();
string sqlFill = "SELECT tblCodons.codonsFullName FROM tblCodons";
OleDbCommand fill = new OleDbCommand(sqlFill, conn2);

OleDbDataReader dataReader = fill.ExecuteReader();

int j = 0;

if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
   while(dataReader.Read())
   {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
       j++;
   }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Probably want to wrap the connection and command objects with using statements.

Comment: hi, @Kamal . I tried your code and i get this error :System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Karmal, good response but no need to increment j.  It'll just be `GetString(0)` each iteration, hence the error that user1017315 is getting.

Comment: @user1017315 - Sorry about that. I just copied and pasted from the q. GetString(int) actually is the position of the column you want the value from. By incrementing it - it would have been looking at column 0, then 1, then 2 and you only have a single column in your select. Well spotted Moo-Juice (nice nick!). Also added the HasRows check in my edit

Comment: now i get this error :System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @user1017315 - where are you getting that cast error because I can't really see anyplace that is casting

Comment: i found the mistake.there was an empty line in the databae. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, as Kamal Mentioned you can't directly set a variable from a sql query as you are trying to do and as the exception states only "SELECT" , "INSERT","UPDATE" and "DELETE" commands can  be use in a query.

Second, I don't know why you need to get the record counts before getting the actual data but if it's really necessary you can write your query like this :

```
var query="SELECT COUNT(tblCodons.codonsFullName) FROM tblCodons;SELECT tblCodons.codonsFullName FROM tblCodons;";
```

Then you can execute both query using a single DataReader. When you execute DataReader.ExequteQuery() it will contain two results.the first one has access to the count and the second one has access to actual data.
[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274)'s an example

Comment: i need it to know when to stop the for action. that part work.can u help me in the other part? see what i wrote to Bert.@Beatles1692